# How to reshape a matrix horizontally using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have matrix `A` of the `size(4,192)`. It consists of 12 matrices of the `size(4,4)` aligned horizontally. I want to get matrix B with the `size(12,16)`. B must get as follows:
suppose

```
A=[y1,y2,y3,...,y12]
```

in which yn is a 4*4 matrix. Then,

```
B=[y1,y4,y7,y10;
   y2,y5,y8,y11;
   y3,y6,y9,y12]
```

Is there an efficient/quicker (using no loop) way to do this using MATLAB?

Comment: I guess you mean: `A=[y1,y2,y3,...,y12]` instead of `A=[y1,y2,y3,...,y16]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
ys1 = 2; % size(1) from submatrix (for the following example, use ys1 = 4 for the actual problem)
ys2 = 2; % size(2) from submatrix (for the following example, use ys2 = 4 for the actual problem)

ns1 = 3; % size(1) of final matrix in terms of submatrix (3 rows)
ns2 = 4; % size(2) of final matrix in terms of submatrix (4 columns)

temp = reshape(A,ys1,ys2,ns1,ns2);
B = reshape(permute(temp,[1 3 2 4]),ys1*ns1,ys2*ns2);
```

Example:

```
A = [11 12   21 22   31 32   41 42   51 52   61 62   71 72   81 82   91 92   101 102   111 112   121 122;
     13 14   23 24   33 34   43 44   53 54   63 64   73 74   83 84   93 94   103 104   113 114   123 124];

B =

    11    12    41    42    71    72   101   102
    13    14    43    44    73    74   103   104
    21    22    51    52    81    82   111   112
    23    24    53    54    83    84   113   114
    31    32    61    62    91    92   121   122
    33    34    63    64    93    94   123   124
```